How to hide text that doesn't fit into a block in Safari?
In Chrome this works by default (see screenshots). Text that does not fit is automatically hidden. But in Safari and Mozilla it does not. Please help

screen this safari
screen this chrome (how to do this in safari?)

 .test
    overflow: hidden
    max-height: 270px

text-overflow: ellipsis it does not suit me



Could you put up a runnable snippet which shows the problem?

Do you know it's always the first line only that fits, or it it completely variable?

What is the code that works in chrome? which version of chrome/os is it you tested? where is your minimal code reproducing your issue that works in chrome ? text-overflow:ellipsis is not working vertically indeed.

you need to target the element directly. this works on my iphone safari


#test{
    overflow:hidden;
    height:16px
 }
<div style="overflow:hidden;height:16px">
this<br>
is
</div>


<div id = 'test'>
this<br>
is
</div>



